# How to fix error "Database is uninitialized and password option is not specified"

Tags: mysql, macos, docker-compose

I'm working on a Mac computer.
I tried to install a nginx server and a MySQL database with docker compose.

Here is the content docker-compose.xaml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
    - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQLROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=demodb
```

When executing the next command: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up`

I get the next error message:

> [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Database is uninitialized and password option is
> not specified db_1 | You need to specify one of the following: db_1 |
>
> - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD db_1 | - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD db_1 | - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD

I will enjoy if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you forgot an underscore in `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`? Change it to:

```
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: Typos should be pointed out in the comments and flagged/voted to close as not reproducible/typo.

Comment: Hello Tobias S.
Sorry for my late feedback. it's working very well now.
Thank you very much